# perform action on bean property struts jstl

Tags: java, jsp, struts, struts-1

I have bean (name=tF) in Struts as of now we are    performing operation on its variables using scriplets  can someone help in removing scriplets and using jsp tags or Struts tag

```
 <bean:define name="tF" property="varin"  id="lvarin"  type="java.lang.Integer"/> 
    <%=(lvarin.intValue()/100.00) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jstl 1.2

```
 <bean:define name="tF" property="varin"  id="lvarin"  type="java.lang.Integer"/> 
    ${(lvarin.intValue()/100.00)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with JSTL syntax : `${tF.varin / 100}`

No scriptlet nor Struts tag are required.